# I cant use the global class vector

Tags: c++, function, class, vector, global

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<vector>
#include "CustomerAccount.h"



vector<CustomerAccount>system;

void CreateAccount(vector<CustomerAccount>&system) {
    string name;
    string email;
    int pass;
    int phone;
    cout << "Pease fill your information : " << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your name : ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Please enter your Email : ";
    cin >> email;
    cout << "Please enter the Password : ";
    cin >> pass;
    cout << "Please enter your phone number : ";
    cin >> phone;
   
    system.push_back(CustomerAccount(name, email, pass, phone));

}

void customer() {
    cout << "Choose one : " << endl;
    cout << " 1)Login to an existing account " << endl;
    cout << " 2)Create a new customer account  " << endl;
    int MainNum{ 0 };
    cin >> MainNum;
    if (MainNum == 1)
        cout << "k";
    else if (MainNum == 2)
        CreateAccount(system);
        
  



}

   This is normal text
```

hi,
I want to make a small restaurant system program, the program will ask the user if he is a admin or a customer.
if he is a customer the program will ask the the user if he want to create a new account .
So I added the Customer account class ,and then I made a vector (system) of Customer account class and I made the vector global.
what the Create Account function  will do is to push back a new object to the  Customer account class every time the function is called.
The problem is that I get error when I use the system vector as a parameter the the function Create Account and I do not know why?

thanks for reading my question

Comment: Why exactly do you need to pass `system` into `CreateAccount` when it is perfectly capable of accessing this vector that's declared globally?

Comment: that is the point , I get an error if didnt passing it

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using global variables, as it's bad design in practice. But, for the sake of answering your question, and making a baseline `CustomerAccount` class without having seen your header declaration...

Your example uses an ambiguous declaration for the global variable name. Furthermore, it's also a native function to execute system calls, so I would recommend using something else.

All that aside, the below should help you along:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class CustomerAccount
{
public:
    CustomerAccount(string name, string email, int pass, int phone);

private:
    string mName;
    string mEmail;
    int mPass;
    int mPhone;
};

CustomerAccount::CustomerAccount(string name, string email, int pass, int phone) 
    : mName(name), mEmail(email), mPass(pass), mPhone(phone)
{
  
}

vector<CustomerAccount> g_system;

void CreateAccount(vector<CustomerAccount>& system) {
    string name;
    string email;
    int pass;
    int phone;
    cout << "Pease fill your information : " << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your name : ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Please enter your Email : ";
    cin >> email;
    cout << "Please enter the Password : ";
    cin >> pass;
    cout << "Please enter your phone number : ";
    cin >> phone;

    system.push_back(CustomerAccount(name, email, pass, phone));
}

void customer() {
    cout << "Choose one : " << endl;
    cout << " 1)Login to an existing account " << endl;
    cout << " 2)Create a new customer account  " << endl;
    int MainNum{ 0 };
    cin >> MainNum;
    if (MainNum == 1)
        cout << "k";
    else if (MainNum == 2)
        CreateAccount(g_system);
}

void main()
{
    customer();
}
```

Update:
To achieve the same result without using a global variable, have the vector contained within the class as a member variable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

struct AccountInfo
{
    string name;
    string email;
    int pass;
    int phone;
};

class CustomerAccounts
{
public:
    CustomerAccounts();
    void CreateNewAccount();

private:
    std::vector<AccountInfo> mAccounts;
};

CustomerAccounts::CustomerAccounts()
{
}


void CustomerAccounts::CreateNewAccount()
{
    AccountInfo info;

    cout << "Pease fill your information : " << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your name : ";
    cin >> info.name;
    cout << "Please enter your Email : ";
    cin >> info.email;
    cout << "Please enter the Password : ";
    cin >> info.pass;
    cout << "Please enter your phone number : ";
    cin >> info.phone;
    
    mAccounts.push_back(info);
}

int main()
{
    CustomerAccounts accounts;

    cout << "Choose one : " << endl;
    cout << " 1)Login to an existing account " << endl;
    cout << " 2)Create a new customer account  " << endl;
    int MainNum{ 0 };
    cin >> MainNum;
    if (MainNum == 1)
        cout << "k";
    else if (MainNum == 2)
        accounts.CreateNewAccount();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ,but I Want to ask you if you suggest another way to do it without global vector, and if you can explain why when you just changed the name of the vector to g_system the error is gone?

Comment: @AymanFreihat If this helped solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted.